# Best way of reading in a Mongo output as JSON without manual preprocessing

Tags: python, node.js, json, mongodb

MongoDB outputs an array of documents as-is, by just pasting document after document, which means I end up with a JSON array that is missing both the wrapping brackets as well as the commas between objects. Usually, I manually preprocess those output files to make them valid JSON. However, my current output is over 500MB big, which means that I cannot open it in Notepad++.

What would be the smartest way to load and process such a huge document? Even if I somehow managed to make it valid JSON, could I perhaps somehow "stream" it object by object, so that I don't have it take up half a gig of memory? Is there a library for that?

Thanks

Comment: The [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) might be helpful to you. I think this question needs a [mre] though because when you say "MongoDB outputs an array of documents as-is", where is this? Is this in Python? If so, what function does this, what is the code that gives this output? If not, are you aware of [pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? You can [edit] the question with a [mre] to make it easier to answer.

Comment: @Kraigolas Not in Python - Just using the mongo shell, I get a file of the specified format. Or rather, I'm not even the one generating the file; a colleague who has access to the databank generated it for me. I personally don't have access to the DB, and can only use data I'm being given.

Comment: @Kraigolas I am already using the library you linked, however I don't think there's a setting for making it easily read in JSON of the specified format? (ie, instead of "[{...}, {...}]" I have "{...}{...}")

Comment: The mongo shell is an administrative tool.  Have you tried using mongoexport to output data as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ cannot open big files , use [textpad](https://www.textpad.com/home) , [ultraedit](https://www.ultraedit.com/) ,vim ot others  to be able to open big files ( those editor use windowing tricks so they don't ocupy all your OS RAM for editing or viewing ...)